# Passing information to other method

Tags: java, methods, constructor

I have trouble with a little section of my code.

I asked the user to give me an answer (using scanner), and know I want to use that information in other method. Then I want to compare it to see if the answer is correct. Her is a little part of my code:

```
public void enterYourName(){
    System.out.println("What is your name?");
    name = input.nextLine();
}
```

And I want to use this information in another method:

```
public void check(String personName){
  if(name.contentEquals("Eric")){
    /* TODO */
  }
}
```

I'm receiving these error messages:

- The type `java.lang.CharSequence` cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files.
- The method `contentEquals(java.lang.StringBuffer)` in the type `java.lang.String` is not applicable for the arguments (`java.lang.String`).

What I am doing wrongly? Also, feel free to correct me if the if the statements are wrong.

Comment: use the name.equalsIgnoreCase("Eric")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `java.lang.CharSequence` should be available for you even without any import - it is part of the JDK. It can't be said easily, why it won't work, but it should.
2. As per its [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_string_contentequals.asp) page, `String.contentEquals` can be parametrized by a `StringBuffer` or by a `CharSequence`. You want to call it by a `String`, it won't work.

(2) can be solved very easily:

- As @AndréMartins says in comment, simply you can use `String.equals(...)` or `String.equalsIgnoreCase(...)`.
- Both `StringBuffer` and `CharSequence` classes have a `toString()` method, what converts them to a `String`.

I also suspect, something might be problematic with the JDK/JRE installation of your machine.